# How to print image that is in byte array using json

Tags: android, wcf

i am developing an app,in that i am calling services using json. In that whatever string data is there i am displaying it using textView. But i want to display image that is in byte array.Below is my code:

```
         t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    String url = "url"
    AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(MainActivity.this);
    mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, data, status);
            if (android.support.v7.appcompat.BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d("###$Request URL", url + "");
                Log.d("###$Response ", data + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Message : ", status.getMessage() + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Code : ", status.getCode() + "");

            }

            if (status.getCode() != -101) {

                String StringData = "" + data;
                try {


                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(StringData);
                    int sd;
                    sd = json.getInt("Stu_id");

                    String Name = json.getString("Stu_FName");
                    String LastName = json.getString("Stu_LName");
                    String Degree = json.getString("DegreeName");


                   t1.setText("Details OF STUDENTS");
                    t1.setText( "First Name: " + Name + "\n" + "Last Name:" + LastName + "\n" + "Degree: " + Degree);

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am not getting how to do that.I am getting data from server like this:

```
{"Comp_Name":null,"DegreeName":"B.E\/B.Tech","EVENT_DATE":null,"Event_LOC":null,"Event_Time":null,"Event_Title":null,"Event_id":null,"HET_UID":null,
  "Image":[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,255,225,0,42,69,120,105,102,0,0,73,73,42,0,8,0,0,0,1,0,49,1,2,0,7,0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,71,111,111,103,108,101,0,0,255,219,0,132,0,3,2,2,3,8,11,11,9,13,11,11,10,10,11,10,11,13,11,10,10,10,13,13,11,10,11,11,10,8,8,14,13,14,8,10,8,13,10,9,10,11,15,10,13,10,14,10,10,8,10,10,10,10,8,10,11,15,10,10,13,8,10,9,8,1,3,4,4,6,5,6,10,6,6,10,16,13,11,13,13,13,16,16,13,16,16,15,16,15,15,15,13,15,15,13,13,13,13,14,15,15,13,14,13,13,15,15,13,15,13,15,13,15,15,13,13,13,13,13,14,13,13,13,13,15,13,13,13,13,255,192,0,17,8,0,88,0,88,3,1,17,0,2,17,1,3,17,1,255,196,0,29,0,0,2,3,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,8,4,5,7,9,3,1,2,0,255,196,0,62,16,0,2,1,1,7,1,5,6,3,5,7,5,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,17,0,4,5,6,18,33,49,65,7,19,34,81,97,8,50,66,113,129,145,161,177,240,35,98,146,193,209,20,51,82,114,178,179,225,9,21,22,115,147,255,196,0,28,1,0,2,2,3,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,5,3,6,0,1,2,7,8,255,196,0,54,17,0,1,4,0,4,3,5,7,4,1,5,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,3,17,4,18,33,49,5,65,81,19,34,97,113,145,20,129,161,177,209,225,240,6,21,35,50,241,51,82,114,130,193,66,255,218,0,12,3,1,0,2,17,3,17,0,63,0,125,38,184,169,232,45,26,29,76,195,114,196,78,53,26,40,233,225,220,250,250,15,206,219,13,180,124,88,108,192,23,29,249,42,140,77,110,49,50,179,78,34,5,252,20,66,89,202,138,178,210,154,87,110,164,249,157,38,134,194,98,49,17,97,168,204,224,208,77,2,121,157,233,54,195,112,217,68,132,177,185,128,26,251,244,215,236,161,227,185,167,49,68,242,77,174,56,97,86,69,137,25,12,179,204,24,70,0,238,132,145,4,37,155,81,0,187,183,3,186,165,28,129,22,103,18,70,131,119,19,77,104,26,222,196,155,255,0,168,27,119,183,82,195,133,100,237,22,28,44,18,110,154,5,95,252,189,219,120,217,218,171,179,102,130,251,120,145,131,68,232,34,9,121,210,84,204,47,40,236,225,89,96,146,75,188,65,68,167,195,173,156,41,140,22,114,11,133,88,89,79,110,230,66,224,98,0,157,141,217,59,130,107,187,167,77,119,234,139,196,181,177,97,114,58,201,46,208,26,203,150,171,157,59,54,158,183,182,139,87,143,40,225,139,196,117,52,216,177,39,127,150,170,126,86,113,100,164,177,98,31,22,145,211,71,128,3,227,86,179,11,146,192,111,18,221,123,163,28,179,3,36,241,67,124,33,154,137,28,12,233,173,209,225,66,4,98,177,0,132,233,30,25,25,157,171,184,166,99,37,196,197,35,29,144,49,164,16,208,199,102,22,72,190,209,164,10,36,155,167,19,117,165,90,117,63,11,195,140,27,241,15,121,34,71,130,92,67,199,122,128,2,216,78,165,172,162,219,110,196,235,204,18,247,136,92,176,217,157,159,254,225,18,184,110,236,72,75,133,4,130,40,237,226,49,163,135,1,123,201,8,73,181,3,18,105,140,43,196,241,247,96,164,3,26,215,237,89,178,176,7,1,125,226,27,149,165,219,52,229,3,64,28,64,178,77,131,129,240,30,227,134,16,195,32,177,96,189,238,118,182,72,57,179,16,104,146,51,115,182,139,173,8,239,243,94,11,129,46,236,64,163,48,220,131,184,220,239,215,174,255,0,106,90,237,27,238,188,82,190,55,195,97,151,14,113,56,96,45,187,215,78,123,105,162,254,155,38,97,50,114,138,126,96,88,149,230,118,169,239,125,142,101,199,248,0,255,0,46,223,149,165,108,142,105,208,161,164,130,57,7,125,160,251,146,135,15,183,15,104,177,252,40,127,204,15,242,54,173,137,159,213,95,93,194,7,34,154,220,135,237,19,112,191,65,27,137,40,52,141,77,175,68,138,245,163,6,143,91,42,141,189,211,95,3,2,173,80,13,154,197,32,34,211,204,14,21,173,254,218,157,168,128,71,215,203,95,59,10,94,107,237,13,229,129,30,37,149,163,239,8,107,204,108,138,170,213,11,65,52,208,74,52,147,77,93,218,238,84,130,219,20,32,226,113,50,199,35,76,113,135,142,164,88,7,200,17,183,95,130,46,88,131,101,160,70,215,151,93,119,220,10,178,57,95,95,122,49,195,251,56,184,202,133,221,158,105,24,105,145,226,114,27,79,4,11,211,168,145,128,0,10,69,29,217,88,26,247,64,150,39,169,161,118,43,253,119,23,15,246,139,107,7,147,65,215,204,146,82,63,105,153,206,170,12,28,172,115,229,221,26,15,51,117,213,31,118,99,145,176,43,148,101,110,224,164,85,58,99,162,133,74,248,142,202,160,179,51,22,119,146,82,242,200,236,204,206,196,146,103,138,38,198,41,191,149,160,244,217,46,198,205,43,233,179,52,2,57,139,215,199,115,240,209,24,200,205,105,169,46,10,131,53,229,248,47,40,81,135,60,50,154,50,215,99,70,216,169,245,86,7,212,91,116,10,97,133,156,192,236,205,244,59,31,49,177,64,87,78,199,238,71,64,145,230,147,186,98,99,47,51,181,42,120,101,145,153,100,29,55,21,166,221,44,190,78,27,4,165,174,149,185,178,155,25,181,163,212,3,98,254,92,147,195,198,36,140,59,177,13,102,112,3,178,180,54,235,197,160,17,245,69,88,206,3,117,157,116,183,52,217,186,139,51,164,150,44,67,226,39,46,199,113,200,143,21,139,99,121,198,249,115,145,161,120,201,35,134,28,48,232,71,235,157,186,90,9,49,25,13,16,129,111,7,124,182,248,142,159,155,168,75,218,168,63,1,22,227,219,27,209,103,236,56,143,5,199,69,237,115,26,244,251,90,15,103,9,135,183,72,182,191,99,220,103,48,98,120,180,23,93,187,183,73,251,230,166,233,15,114,234,204,61,65,101,0,117,102,2,219,16,128,84,209,99,94,93,103,146,236,54,1,128,97,144,196,145,172,106,18,33,68,94,137,79,83,241,121,177,220,146,77,106,77,75,21,201,106,222,247,18,78,167,212,169,23,108,107,13,135,96,241,165,106,118,53,60,249,150,59,219,17,231,9,44,187,177,199,243,166,139,222,60,227,117,233,40,63,81,248,87,159,235,108,181,195,184,115,255,0,250,140,171,75,166,100,45,189,65,31,175,47,233,231,229,109,165,242,96,192,52,1,10,90,227,112,183,167,175,75,96,80,28,51,155,182,170,53,246,91,72,177,129,81,75,138,208,219,97,76,99,181,149,123,68,93,175,15,115,150,120,191,191,129,25,210,163,102,10,53,21,250,129,183,145,3,157,237,4,177,135,181,17,134,149,208,59,78,107,155,18,251,107,227,171,177,137,106,54,178,206,196,163,63,116,120,228,150,9,178,206,32,187,21,63,107,20,217,218,118,41,19,160,123,119,9,222,255,0,166,38,14,35,151,16,188,178,144,201,20,40,28,142,21,154,86,42,58,212,148,83,205,60,35,214,210,7,89,69,224,225,50,60,50,183,41,231,189,94,241,219,199,26,130,143,119,225,90,115,239,22,21,62,160,31,91,111,85,232,145,123,30,12,81,35,53,107,204,221,116,214,149,93,227,44,223,69,89,165,74,249,23,224,252,199,30,86,213,34,135,24,195,208,107,90,125,2,243,139,4,189,173,0,42,107,77,245,249,250,158,105,233,95,151,91,106,138,235,247,124,59,181,117,143,10,250,41,168,216,164,102,160,56,3,114,71,20,243,168,231,245,197,186,4,174,196,152,89,244,204,211,124,143,208,169,183,30,209,177,5,59,157,107,78,167,125,205,57,231,253,92,125,250,14,33,65,55,6,133,205,238,247,79,135,211,252,34,156,23,180,59,180,191,34,72,0,237,198,196,131,212,215,106,122,113,210,210,7,90,170,227,56,84,144,119,143,168,248,88,228,189,175,247,255,0,225,60,31,95,34,63,29,185,22,148,20,163,33,247,160,236,123,23,93,50,33,255,0,9,251,80,244,245,183,46,43,135,55,75,92,95,206,55,123,176,189,76,171,178,9,158,149,230,154,141,129,40,70,11,125,38,242,249,151,240,54,39,84,96,31,149,169,145,226,28,213,244,22,39,244,108,50,183,248,220,153,31,102,140,159,134,193,118,98,160,5,146,70,145,133,57,210,59,180,83,230,42,24,252,182,234,109,105,193,59,60,121,143,53,229,220,71,5,251,102,37,208,180,217,20,47,204,89,62,132,15,138,14,246,141,246,141,198,46,228,67,117,86,123,196,149,1,62,21,10,40,93,141,106,160,84,13,32,84,182,154,53,42,203,60,211,6,110,105,5,144,68,192,72,179,203,239,249,170,88,223,48,118,130,230,179,94,111,8,127,194,140,85,7,7,221,7,211,173,108,161,248,155,254,165,66,37,121,58,232,180,124,183,142,231,232,128,116,190,202,104,43,251,69,87,31,93,75,170,159,38,4,83,98,45,19,49,206,5,73,103,158,170,235,47,123,90,231,75,187,232,146,15,237,27,208,180,39,75,157,205,105,28,135,73,39,255,0,106,210,159,102,76,198,10,213,70,94,47,188,223,69,184,101,111,104,156,167,125,211,12,138,97,157,248,73,129,141,245,26,108,9,33,100,210,41,82,140,235,206,246,53,147,49,250,2,141,135,17,44,127,233,187,78,135,84,101,62,7,3,209,225,112,232,131,81,4,248,141,1,167,136,13,252,71,86,196,112,118,230,211,121,39,240,113,102,63,187,59,104,157,47,150,190,28,180,235,126,106,70,87,207,26,199,119,38,218,170,0,234,64,39,226,247,117,108,72,35,98,41,201,38,189,130,150,113,46,29,217,255,0,44,91,85,159,15,183,201,83,118,165,124,238,99,50,30,2,154,159,49,165,141,121,234,57,29,8,54,199,157,21,92,157,215,33,214,225,120,188,206,66,10,151,144,211,234,198,193,189,192,13,82,230,135,57,221,208,159,252,103,30,201,206,229,92,17,67,200,181,80,152,28,121,175,125,195,193,198,162,132,58,39,3,99,98,181,179,143,225,87,28,59,188,5,82,34,11,2,221,20,84,214,157,121,39,235,107,68,25,89,16,201,178,243,44,83,230,151,22,227,136,61,241,191,159,229,4,164,226,120,182,123,188,177,189,67,118,119,105,79,188,74,41,142,61,244,40,51,54,251,29,76,85,37,33,217,168,173,176,8,101,146,57,164,239,187,65,231,255,0,159,100,20,206,121,213,161,84,102,27,230,126,71,88,158,11,197,227,197,24,212,151,118,49,132,117,44,236,111,29,218,4,104,118,26,76,106,172,117,26,138,5,98,29,6,31,179,46,15,0,244,252,41,59,102,156,73,69,186,125,233,48,25,59,43,222,5,215,89,27,232,167,215,139,87,195,133,23,114,79,11,13,128,178,235,254,90,205,8,210,20,143,79,119,27,73,222,17,64,204,16,184,72,217,161,144,75,33,247,116,170,108,199,251,192,70,146,219,11,27,37,213,206,3,222,130,196,189,241,255,0,80,79,186,253,124,16,100,89,223,51,94,155,185,158,233,121,104,77,0,146,75,156,131,125,32,146,28,93,163,101,0,236,11,192,181,166,173,107,93,34,105,160,100,125,232,222,47,207,243,230,161,195,205,35,199,125,191,10,250,162,172,149,218,174,107,193,136,90,188,215,34,192,176,230,88,199,21,86,98,53,170,244,82,192,138,146,9,217,108,70,31,27,179,92,143,178,52,58,132,209,221,179,78,31,136,194,47,144,82,161,6,133,31,24,160,220,121,211,130,126,50,73,229,72,47,90,236,194,194,123,128,198,87,240,74,108,59,64,122,120,31,15,146,15,237,223,53,223,103,194,47,154,60,114,67,17,174,196,120,106,171,33,167,238,171,51,210,191,9,226,182,195,168,73,56,174,19,176,121,45,26,27,175,162,69,59,43,185,160,101,110,14,161,249,217,92,166,208,156,52,134,189,174,61,83,35,136,118,125,138,62,226,132,250,154,126,118,15,246,57,152,52,32,175,96,195,126,177,136,10,115,74,190,237,58,245,43,67,135,220,27,221,209,23,122,163,169,21,148,169,232,65,211,164,154,238,9,243,180,248,140,208,97,203,78,224,125,151,157,98,167,110,35,17,52,205,217,239,53,228,181,108,15,43,101,233,99,2,77,246,30,235,21,167,213,88,31,202,212,200,156,208,123,197,68,224,224,52,66,55,243,147,46,178,50,35,0,87,118,121,165,102,234,60,43,222,57,223,209,125,43,210,211,56,185,219,108,182,14,154,162,143,252,223,46,58,133,142,90,185,248,90,129,127,138,180,31,80,45,163,24,13,231,229,201,104,56,222,180,162,97,184,102,92,191,147,31,120,209,78,188,52,114,21,212,62,96,209,135,163,43,0,120,230,182,150,49,148,105,241,217,105,238,35,113,97,94,199,217,117,210,236,132,153,166,149,186,9,100,5,71,200,42,129,248,125,109,220,151,150,202,128,59,49,208,44,175,180,91,189,219,75,84,1,96,227,39,50,149,192,5,144,246,41,218,116,184,109,245,174,203,78,238,74,201,24,99,69,71,173,31,150,11,189,67,110,9,169,98,5,105,75,174,14,67,146,202,93,218,12,197,157,121,173,211,180,28,98,231,20,83,184,58,161,154,239,50,238,104,26,177,185,147,110,116,134,96,6,222,21,32,114,13,153,23,116,79,36,153,184,140,25,15,254,205,249,13,143,191,159,138,67,50,216,147,80,241,233,21,243,178,249,124,21,41,143,35,64,87,93,229,236,171,12,238,205,87,197,78,108,245,211,158,210,129,210,209,80,226,28,214,7,29,233,41,94,208,56,67,221,37,133,212,146,2,120,73,243,5,197,62,149,178,238,49,1,105,32,141,192,40,188,38,49,152,134,23,198,118,114,171,203,221,169,57,143,114,105,75,80,157,7,121,56,18,2,16,222,100,204,249,98,241,119,253,171,0,198,66,192,114,196,240,40,6,251,10,47,151,222,204,34,99,218,234,104,67,151,52,238,80,125,202,229,144,92,133,121,216,10,10,107,73,60,39,215,160,249,138,253,41,99,234,81,201,69,76,228,86,174,248,254,91,185,37,220,194,224,232,106,106,86,174,165,126,73,115,187,26,128,106,78,192,83,110,2,217,26,95,98,148,192,214,232,131,27,237,196,233,166,170,129,96,123,39,187,66,137,5,163,85,159,99,249,244,222,20,215,233,243,180,236,134,138,18,105,5,37,227,56,99,111,21,238,25,1,217,15,136,244,1,136,27,147,176,234,126,66,214,140,43,123,133,87,222,243,156,20,195,246,155,154,37,124,51,115,226,212,168,160,108,0,101,53,80,167,99,183,136,208,10,13,59,111,82,72,114,38,89,203,90,225,212,37,50,250,36,94,182,232,81,73,237,119,156,93,67,252,107,191,74,143,235,105,181,232,16,126,210,224,235,89,71,180,7,98,87,171,253,198,88,227,72,222,116,163,192,73,163,6,14,172,202,172,58,200,129,144,43,120,11,20,38,154,67,164,120,201,100,145,142,47,26,80,248,115,69,96,167,142,46,238,218,159,143,95,34,145,44,149,135,220,37,170,183,206,156,31,183,242,54,167,203,96,171,123,13,132,27,158,125,159,177,6,145,29,29,152,49,212,177,215,112,117,61,52,29,137,127,37,169,106,241,189,5,156,225,49,34,170,181,81,140,31,106,78,186,14,75,194,111,103,60,96,43,55,123,60,116,93,215,198,104,20,212,6,33,180,168,21,170,212,211,81,216,123,196,49,18,245,165,203,176,12,53,151,243,201,125,201,189,139,99,49,178,153,36,99,9,126,14,236,54,39,81,106,144,43,182,213,111,82,14,214,89,139,157,149,221,26,174,91,135,115,29,68,162,236,195,151,110,168,116,3,81,231,94,150,86,199,19,170,45,218,44,235,180,76,225,5,219,76,96,238,121,244,81,215,111,195,169,161,242,179,44,54,28,201,101,38,197,226,3,69,47,78,198,243,29,196,36,237,120,141,206,169,53,68,92,120,74,211,247,142,161,66,120,17,0,65,30,38,169,210,199,17,129,149,249,123,58,20,40,242,65,97,177,1,129,217,129,54,87,166,97,199,46,243,133,12,211,50,45,116,199,28,44,20,117,217,168,212,27,208,17,25,28,245,173,142,102,13,224,81,35,231,244,65,62,73,30,73,160,61,77,124,7,205,6,205,134,225,46,64,238,239,132,249,119,71,115,255,0,194,131,206,161,206,199,109,197,45,59,112,213,205,115,103,243,252,166,24,246,217,140,251,253,252,163,203,115,75,55,119,233,172,69,210,86,49,176,29,85,141,195,218,131,63,160,33,47,26,143,77,91,216,103,254,155,196,85,19,167,154,223,180,179,118,238,178,241,158,177,30,253,239,18,42,6,146,66,238,34,217,106,199,83,16,191,14,163,86,32,108,9,52,160,216,36,199,240,25,224,102,96,210,90,6,251,215,137,240,241,245,86,12,7,18,14,166,60,140,223,63,186,218,241,59,165,242,253,119,73,97,33,128,28,87,229,183,31,162,45,83,143,248,205,57,89,163,148,131,153,168,125,50,150,116,102,82,209,191,134,148,44,73,3,166,213,216,88,147,48,173,209,62,209,33,25,85,231,105,25,191,13,184,192,17,221,67,129,189,88,123,223,63,215,79,75,15,20,18,98,31,76,9,124,147,8,197,185,47,39,180,75,148,190,62,249,69,122,80,150,30,132,26,21,250,138,31,91,89,227,225,109,3,188,239,68,161,248,226,237,130,165,75,214,84,142,78,250,75,193,103,45,195,141,75,199,135,246,74,164,81,121,12,106,84,238,8,230,205,227,130,54,10,9,107,221,156,230,114,58,186,255,0,102,101,12,146,43,43,13,152,110,167,212,26,26,126,129,7,113,99,52,228,178,215,238,247,60,228,83,79,213,24,110,124,192,215,171,214,148,36,113,191,39,10,218,162,196,47,216,208,33,85,123,192,42,75,144,192,183,146,131,213,189,116,211,106,19,231,206,171,73,233,188,100,124,155,39,135,187,26,22,188,39,95,181,172,133,211,183,115,175,154,171,181,241,60,119,117,10,147,28,200,185,58,40,201,72,134,177,251,134,191,149,182,195,51,157,78,118,158,106,66,230,180,88,9,99,237,191,42,92,227,159,246,35,194,84,18,41,193,181,195,135,67,218,68,76,137,94,42,82,215,14,207,162,8,203,189,168,227,120,107,21,71,233,86,66,118,223,211,161,255,0,131,111,39,253,85,195,48,145,226,0,128,83,143,246,3,96,119,20,57,19,185,27,109,160,87,94,11,142,157,209,127,46,189,58,248,218,186,198,61,177,243,131,47,116,160,234,60,116,3,241,59,90,161,23,13,205,185,209,60,126,59,46,195,85,146,99,184,230,59,121,146,178,43,78,238,104,80,171,48,61,118,8,106,41,230,173,176,169,36,212,214,201,12,13,136,101,96,74,100,145,210,27,114,33,195,123,45,186,48,6,72,163,135,110,3,72,207,254,249,69,63,199,229,75,22,26,20,89,2,149,136,246,11,130,83,103,146,191,186,224,144,104,15,186,195,126,126,20,167,77,85,4,91,179,24,11,121,2,163,193,178,230,99,185,63,119,11,172,145,187,80,172,149,26,77,11,86,160,26,86,148,168,21,169,2,134,209,128,66,231,41,10,219,26,205,19,192,66,202,134,38,60,26,234,141,254,78,63,38,1,186,233,28,219,45,116,77,110,190,93,187,64,41,77,245,163,108,175,93,193,242,39,169,29,9,228,122,131,93,230,91,181,255,217],"Position_Name":null,"Spec_name":"Computer Science","State_Name":null,"Stu_FName":"sdsff","Stu_LName":"fgfgfgg"
```

Comment: Sending an image via JSON is just a horrible idea.  Send a url to download the file at instead.  Sending the image via json is just horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Parse your byte array `Image` from your json to a byte array variable.
2. Convert your byte array to bitmap like below

   ```
   Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length); // image is your byte array
   ```
3. Set the bitmap bmap to an `ImageView`

   ```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
   ```

**Update**

Try this:

a. Get your byte array like this

```
JsonArray arr = json.getJSONArray("Image");
```

b. Create byte array object with size of your Json array `arr`

```
byte[] imageArr = new byte[arr.length()];
```

c. Iterate to insert elements into your byte array

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    imageArr[i] = arr.getInt(i);
}
```

Then follow the steps 1 and 2 to achieve your goal.

Comment: String image=json.getString("Image");

                        byte[] data1 = image.getBytes();
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data1, 0, data1.length);
                        i.setImageBitmap(bmp);    I did like this,but its showing error "SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null" in logcat

Comment: @user6798766 why are you using `String image=json.getString("Image");` ? try my updated answer.